# Plane pendulum at an angle (Goldstein 12.11)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, adiabatic

I am struggling not only to come up with action/angle variables for the system, but more generally an appropriate Hamiltonian that takes into account the tilt of the plane. The system is as follows:

> "A plane pendulum of small amplitude (length) A is constrained to move on an inclined plane, as shown in the accompanying figure. How does its amplitude change when the inclination angle $\alpha$ of the plane is changed slowly?"

[image]

This is clearly an adiabatic invariant problem, I just am struggling on the setup of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the angle between the pendulum rope and the perpendicular line that connects O to the horizontal plane (let this line has length H) $\theta$ then to find the height of the pendulum bob from the horizontal surface is $(H-Acos(\theta))sin(\alpha)$. To simplify the solution assume the length of the pendulum rope is A such that it is the length of the perpendicular line H such assumption doesn't change the characteristics of the solution. Then consider z-axis perpendicular to the horizontal plane then the equations wrt axis' are z=$(A-Acos(\theta))$ and y=$(A-Asin(\theta))cos(\alpha)$ and from the height equation potential energy U=$mgA(1-cos(\theta))sin(\alpha)$ and to find kinetic energy T=$\frac{1}{2}m(z'y')^2$. Rest seems to a lot of algebra. For the geometry part [height from the horizontal surface](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UC4mFP8w0DJdgSBvmDo5YruQp8BYsP47/view?usp=drivesdk) and [slanted surface](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UDIW-O_qldjxptHkk03nlZn7i35JyP09/view?usp=drivesdk).

Comment: I am struggling with reproducing your result, so I have opened a question on the math stack, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909170/fraction-of-an-opposite-side-of-a-triangle please help me out there :)

Comment: @LopeyTall I edited the answer and added  pictures if they are not enough we can continue on math SE question.

Comment: Your first picture "from horizontal" doesn't add anything to the set up we already have. I don't see how we can just tack on a sin alpha to the answer from the second picture.

Comment: @LopeyTall  there is a right triangle that is the hypotenuse is H-A$cos(\theta)$ and the height is the formula in the answer and from the first picture you can deduce that it is the hypotenuse times the $sin(\alpha)$.